child item is not using parent coordinates
I have a problem with PySide coordinate system. I create a custom item (NodeItem) that inherits from QGraphicsRectItem and is positioned in the scene. This custom item has a child (LabelItem) that inherits from QGraphicsTextItem. When I add the parent item (NodeItem) to the scene is positioned in 150,150 in scene coordinates but the child LabelItem is positioned in scene coordinates not in his parent coordinates (NodeItem).
As you see in the image, "R1" LabelItem is in the origin of the scene not the origin of the NodeItem (the rectangle).
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QApplication
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor, QPen, QBrush
from PySide6.QtCore import QRectF
from PySide6 import QtWidgets

class LabelItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setZValue(2)

class NodeItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height)

     
        pen = QPen(QColor("#000000"))  
        brush = QBrush(QColor("#FFD700"))  
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.setBrush(brush)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)

        # LabelItem created as a child of this item
        self.label = LabelItem(self) #Child item
        self.label.setPlainText("R1")
        self.update_label_position()
        print(self.label.parentItem())
    def update_label_position(self):
        
        self.label.setPos(0, 0)  #Child item positioned at 0,0
    
class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        # Node item creation and positioned at 150,150 of the scene
        node_item = NodeItem(150, 150, 100, 50)
        self.scene().addItem(node_item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    view = MyGraphicsView()
    view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 300)
    view.show()

    app.exec()



I changed the class from QGraphicsRectItem to QGraphicsPixmapItem and it worked. It seems there is a conflict, at least in this case, when a child item from QGraphicsRectItem is positioned using the parent coordinates, the doc says nothing about it.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import  QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QApplication

from PySide6.QtCore import QRectF
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtSvg

class LabelItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setZValue(2)


class NodeItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, svg_file, x, y):
        super().__init__(svg_file)
        self.setPos(x, y)  # Position the item in the scene

        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)

        # LabelItem created as a child of this item
        self.label = LabelItem(self)  # Child item
        self.label.setPlainText("R1")
        self.update_label_position()

    def update_label_position(self):
        self.label.setPos(0,0)  # Center the label in the rect


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap

        # Node item creation and positioned at 150, 150 of the scene
        node_item = NodeItem( QPixmap("add-note.svg"), 150, 150)
        self.scene().addItem(node_item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    view = MyGraphicsView()
    view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 300)
    view.show()

    app.exec()




There is absolutely no conflict at all, it works as expected and its behavior is also explained in almost any QGraphicsItem related documentation, such as QGraphicsScene.addRect()): "the item's geometry is provided in item coordinates, and its position is initialized to (0, 0). For example, if a QRect(50, 50, 100, 100) is added, its top-left corner will be at (50, 50) relative to the origin in the item's coordinate system".

Even if the visual result may seem similar due to inexperience with relative coordinate systems, doing QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, width, height) is not the same as QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, width, height) followed by setPos(x, y), which is exactly what you're doing with the QGraphicsPixmapItem above. Please take your time to properly study the Graphics View introduction, specifically the section related to its coordinate system.

How is that? I am doing
class NodeItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
def init(self, x, y, width, height):
super().init(x, y, width, height)
with
node_item = NodeItem(150, 150, 100, 50)
which is not
QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, width, height)
but
QGraphicsRectItem(150, 150, width, height)

QGraphicsRectItem(150, 150, width, height) creates an item showing a rectangle at (150, 150, width, height), but its position will still be (0, 0). If you do QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, width, height) followed by setPos(150, 150), the result will look identical, but the item will actually be at (150, 150), and, therefore, the child item will be properly positioned. The contents of a QGraphicsItem (what it actually shows) do not always coincide with its origin point (0, 0 in local coordinates). You have to consider graphics items as transparent paper sheets with something »

» drawn inside of it. The item's position is where you position the paper sheet, the position of what's inside of it is always relative to the sheet. I can have one sheet with a square drawn adjacent to its top left corner, and another similar square drawn in the middle of the sheet. Then I can move one of those sheets in order to get both squares shown at the same place, but the sheets will have very different positions. In your original example, you drew a rectangle on one sheet at its (150, 150); QGraphicsPixmapItem by default always shows the image on the top left corner of its "sheet" »

» (unless setOffset() is called) so you actually moved that sheet by calling setPos(). In reality, those two "sheets" have quite different positions. Since child items are always positioned using the coordinate system of the parent, the result is that your original code was shown in the "unmoved" sheet, while that of this answer has moved the sheet. I strongly suggest you to read the links above and the answers in the posts for which I marked yours as a duplicate. Also consider this related post.

I got it. I did super().setPos(150,150) inside NodeItem class and it worked. I think I understood. This is the position in parent coordinates, in this case the scene. Now, the item local coordinates will set (150,150) to (0,0). From the doc: "At item's position is the coordinate of the item's center point in its parent's coordinate system; sometimes referred to as parent coordinates. The scene is in this sense regarded as all parent-less items' "parent". Top level items' position are in scene coordinates." I didn't have an understanding of the position concept. Thank you!

The second code worked because the super() in the constructor have not the coordinates  super().init(svg_file) so setPos is setting the position. In the former code was moving to 150,150 from pos 0,0. Thank you!

You're very welcome! Consider that the concept of "parent" has to be considered as the "reference context", and always ends up "somewhere" at some point, which becomes the absolute reference (similarly to absolute paths for file systems). Regarding coordinates, the behavior for QGraphicsItems is not so different than that of widgets: for the former, it eventually is the scene (if parentItem() is None, it's the scene), for the latter it's the screen. Similarly (but not identical), item coordinates can be mapped to the scene by using mapToScene() as widgets do that with mapToGlobal().
